# Set of 3 numbers equal whose sum is equal to T form 3 unsorted arrays ABC

Tags: algorithm

We have three arrays A, B and C, unsorted, each array having n numbers. We want to 
find a set of three numbers a, b and c where a ϵ A, b ϵ B and c ϵ C, such that Sum of 
these numbers is equal to T. (a + b + c = T)

Please solve this for complexity ***O(n.logn)*** and ***O(n.logn<sup>2</sup>)*** (TIME COMPLEXITY)

Comment: Just "want to find"? Brute force. Hint: be specific

Comment: Please solve this for complexity nlgn and nlgn^2

Comment: Complexity of what? Time? Space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The obvious way is to just brute force.

```
for(i in a)
    for(j in b)
        for(k in c)
            if(i+j+k == key)
                //add triple to the result set
```

This has a time complexity of O(n<sup>3</sup>) though. We can do better than that if we sort array c.

```
sort(c)
for(i in a)
    x = key-i
    for(j in b)
        x -= j
        if(c.binary_search(x) != -1) //assuming -1 means element doesn't exist
            //add i, j, and x, to the result set
```

This has a complexity of O(n<sup>2</sup>.log n)

An even further optimization would be to sort arrays b and c.

```
sort(c)
sort(b)
for(i in a)
    x = key-i
    bi = 0
    ci = n-1
    while(ci >= 0 && bi < n)
        if(b[bi]+c[ci] == x)
            //add to result set
        else if(b[bi]+c[ci] > x)
            ci--
        else
            bi++
```

This will run in O(n<sup>2</sup>).

EDIT:

O(n.log n) solution

```
sort(a)
sort(b)
sort(c)
ai = 0
bi = n-1
while(ai < n && bi >= 0)
    x = key-(a[ai]+b[bi])
    if(x < c[0])
        bi--
    else if(x > c[n-1])
        ai++
    else if(c.binary_search(x) != -1) //assuming -1 means element doesn't exist
        //add to result set
```

EDIT: ***I realized that this O(n. log n) algorithm is incorrect. It may never halt. I will leave it in the post nevertheless in case someone can suggest a fix for it.***

Comment: sort(c) and sort(B) also cost some complexity,so total isn't O(n^2) .....!comment plz

Comment: both arrays have size n, sorting each one will be O(n log n) using merge sort. total complexity = n log n + n log n + n^2 = 2 n log n + n^2 which is O(n^2)

Comment: thanks
can you please solve this for complexity nlgn and nlgn^2???

Comment: what will be the complexity of sort(a) sort(b)&sort(c)????

Comment: Same as before, n log n for each. I am sorry, but you really need to study the basics from a good Algorithms textbook.

Answer (score 0):

***O(n<sup>2</sup>)*** algorithm:

1 - Using merge sort, merge the arrays into a sorted one

2 - Now solve the [3SUM problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3SUM#Quadratic_algorithm) with a little moddification

```
 S = Mergesort(A,B,C);
 for i=0 to n-3 do
    a = S[i];
    k = i+1;
    l = n-1;
    while (k<l) do
       b = S[k];
       c = S[l];
       if (a+b+c == T) then
          output a, b, c;
          exit;
       else if (a+b+c > 0) then
          l = l - 1;
       else
          k = k + 1;
       end   
    end
 end
output "not found"//or return whatever you want!
```

> When the integers are in the range [-u, ... , u], 3SUM can be solved in O(n + u.log u) time by representing the input set S as a bit vector, computing the set S+S of all pairwise sums as a discrete convolution using the Fast Fourier transform, and finally comparing this set to -S.

Comment: it seems like you cannot guarantee that a ϵ A, b ϵ B and c ϵ C.

Comment: @SamyArous Yes, obviously it's not possible always. A=B=C=[2,2,2] , T = 3, what is the answer?

Comment: according to the constraints, if you can't verify this property, you should return False.

Comment: @SamyArous- That's trivial.

Answer (score 0):

First sort the B and C arrays

```
B.sort()
C.sort()
```

Now we will modify a little the [3Sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3SUM) algorithm to search values from B and C. We will use the same trick but on two different arrays instead of one single array

```
def Find_Sum(A, B, C, T):
    for a in A:
        bi = 0
        ci = len(C)
        while(bi < len(B) and ci >= 0):
            b = B[bi]
            c = C[ci]
            s = a + b + c
            if s == T:
                return (a, b, c)
            elif s > T:
                ci -= 1
            else:
                bi += 1
    return False
```

This algorithm is O(n²).

As specified in the wikipedia page, you can achieve a O(n + nlogn) by computing A+B and comparing it with C. I'll let you do the research for this one.

Comment: You don't have to sort A, just B and C

Comment: That's absolutely true, fixed

Comment: what is O(n + nlogn) exactly?

Comment: it means the time complexity is n +ulogu